# Foundation 4 "end" class

Tags: zurb-foundation

How can i have a row with less columns then 12 using Foundation 4.

On Foundation 3 there is the ".end" class that you can use but I don't know how to simulate this on Foundation 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `end` class is still available in F4, that enables the last column to float left. So if you have something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns panel">1st column</div>
    <div class="large-9 columns panel">column float at right</div>
</div>
```

whose second column is floated at the right side, so you have "two spaces" in between columns. And you add the `end` class to the last column such that you have this

```
<div class="large-9 columns panel end">column float at right</div>
```

then you will see that the second column will be pulled just beside the first column.

Comment: Is it just me or do you still think that Foundation 3 docs' are way better then Foundation 4 ?

Comment: I'm afraid it is. But nobody's perfect yeah, I just hope they update the docs soon. For now, digging into the css the js files is the best  way of learning more about F4 - to learn those that are not in the docs.